# Left Join PHP/SQL with LIKE and logical AND

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following Mysql query where im trying to run a left join to define a pages table with a images table.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages
                    WHERE `fname` LIKE '%$fname%' AND `lname` LIKE '%$lname%' AND `city` LIKE '%$citysearch%' AND `state` LIKE '%$statesearch%' AND `activities` LIKE '%$locationsearch%' AND `startyr` LIKE '%$startyearsearch%' AND `endyr` LIKE '%$endyearsearch%'
                     LEFT JOIN `images.pgname` WHERE `pages.pgname` = 'images.pgname' LIMIT $start, $perpage
                ");
```

I get "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 72"

What im trying to do is join the pages table with the images table. 
The pages table has the following feilds:
fname, lname, city, state, activities, startyr, endyr, pgname

And the images table has the following fields: 
pgname, id, imageUrl, username

What I want to do is return all of the images where pages.pgname is equal to images.pgname, and return the image's URL with imageUrl.

Any and all help is welcome!

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit on what you're trying to get as a result, you might get more helpful answers.

Comment: @Niko, i just edited the question right now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to join a column "images.pgname"? You can only join complete tables. Also, the JOIN needs to be before the WHERE clause.

Now, lets decipher that procedure: if you need to select values from multiple tables, you first list all the values you'd like to select. In this case, that is a) all columns from pages (`pages.*`) and b) the imageUrl from images (`images.imageUrl`):

```
SELECT pages.*, images.imageUrl
```

Then you specify the table(s) from which you're selecting, just as usual:

```
FROM pages
```

Then you do the join. Left join means, that the database will *try* to find a corresponding row in the other table (images). It is not necessary that this row actually exists. However, you do the join by specifying the table and the condition that defines the connection:

```
LEFT JOIN images ON pages.pgname = images.pgname
```

The rest stays the same:

```
WHERE pages.fname LIKE '%$fname%' AND pages.lname LIKE '%$lname%' AND pages.city LIKE '%$citysearch%' AND pages.state LIKE '%$statesearch%' AND pages.activities LIKE '%$locationsearch%' AND pages.startyr LIKE '%$startyearsearch%' AND pages.endyr LIKE '%$endyearsearch%'
LIMIT $start, $perpage
```

---

However, if you have multiple images per page, you need to do the joining the other way around:

```
SELECT pages.*, images.imageUrl
FROM images
JOIN pages ON pages.pgname = images.pgname
WHERE ...
```

Comment: also suggested using mysqli or PDO

Comment: What im trying to do is join the pages table with the images table. 
The pages table has the following feilds:
fname, lname, city, state, activities, startyr, endyr, pgname

And the images table has the following fields: 
pgname, id, imageUrl, username

What I want to do is return all of the images where pages.pgname is equal to images.pgname, and return the image's URL with imageUrl.

Comment: @ThelsonRichardson I've updated my answer, please let me know if that addresses your issue correctly.

Comment: Im still unable to fix my problem.